# How to connect localhost wordpress project to database?

Tags: database

Hello i have an localhost wordpress project. The last thing i need to do is connect a database. Because i get an message in my browser that there is no Error establishing a database connection. Can anyone tell me step-by-step how to do this? This beneath is where the `dev.js` for asks. My project runs on Node.js

```
$GLOBALS['DB_HOST']           = 'localhost';
$GLOBALS['DB_NAME']           = 'name';
$GLOBALS['DB_USER']           = 'username';
$GLOBALS['DB_PASSWORD']       = 'password';
$GLOBALS['DB_TABLE_PREFIX']   = 'prefix_';
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: This is the error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`